# How to interact with a wordpress plugin based on a URL coded into a QR code

Tags: php, wordpress, url, plugins

I'm trying to use a QR code, that every user on my website with an account would get when they sign up. This QR code when scanned will redirect to a URL that I then want to interact with a plug-in I have active on Wordpress.

I need to execute this code in order to fulfill the action I need fulfilled when a QR code is scanned.
PHP Follows:

```
mycred_add( 'Attended event.', $user_id, -1, '1 deducted for attending event, QR code scan.' );
```

I am a **complete** newbie at web development. I have a background of intermediate Java and VBA.

Where I have reached: I am able to generate a QR code for any URL accurately, also my Users can purchase points. The final piece is to figure out the URL to plugin command.
My plug-in is myCred.me
It has a remote API 
[Here](http://codex.mycred.me/classes/mycred_remote/#methods)

ANY direction how to achieve this would be appreciate, as far as the rules of the board go, I am not asking for a recommendation of alternatives or products or anything of that sort.
Only, programming wise how would I go about setting this up.

E.G. Should I be embedding a PHP script into a webpage that reads the $user variable from the link itself, or along those lines?

Comment: set 2 variables in the url of the QRcode, an action and the user id. Create a function that when $_GET['action'] is present in the url executes the mycred_add using the $_GET['user'] and $user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example QRcode url to a custom page:

```
http://www.anysite.com/mycredapi.php?action=setpoints&userid=5
```

php function:

```
function set_mycred_points($user_id) {
   mycred_add( 'Attended event.', $user_id, -1, '1 deducted for attending event, QR code scan.' );
}

if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'setpoints' && isset($_GET['userid'])) {
   set_mycred_points($_GET['userid'])
}
```

note that I would include a secret key as an additional parameter and hash the parameters for a bit more security

Comment: thanks for this bux, as I understand this. i will have a webpage titled mycredapi and that will have a php script embedded that uses that snippet of script code you put there, which will talk to my plugin. I'm willing to compensate if this works out for me if you want!