# How to add points to a logged-in user after reading a QR code (URL) with MyCred and WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, qr-code

I'm trying to create a WordPress project for a local shop who want to provide points to a client when this arrives to the shop and reads a certain QR code related to the shop.

I'm using the below project to read QR codes using the mobile camera.
[https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR](https://stackoverflow.com)

I found something similar, but this project is for any QR Code assigned to a user.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44809685/how-to-interact-with-a-wordpress-plugin-based-on-a-url-coded-into-a-qr-code](https://stackoverflow.com)

What I need is to add a certain number of points to the logged-in user who reads the QR Code.

Also, I would greatly appreciate it if I can set the time limit for the use of the QR code itself.

For example, with a link like below

```
http://www.anysite.com/shop-page?action=setpoints&points=10&shop=1&date=20231030
```

**Points**: number of points to be added to the logged-in user

**Shop**: indicate to which shop belongs the QR code

**Date**: validity of the QR code.  This code would be valid till the 30th of October 2023.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to accomplish this. Please note that I am not seeking suggestions for alternatives or products. Only, programming wise, how would I go about setting this up.

Comment: You'd check for the existence of these URL parameters, and then you'd perform the necessary action ... That check could be implemented just "globally" in the functions.php, or in a custom plugin, if desired. Or you could set up a specific route explicitly dedicated to just this task, and then redirect the user to the shop page afterwards.

Comment: _"Date: validity of the QR code. This code would be valid till the 30th of October 2023."_ - once I know that URL, what would be stopping me from requesting it again in my browser after that day - and simply manipulating the value of that parameter? Or to make have `points=5000`, instead of the 10 you wanted me to get? You should include a hash of (parameter values + a secret), so that you can verify the values are genuine and have not been manipulated.

Comment: Going to try  $user_id = get_current_user_id();

Comment: As for the date validity, it is just to avoid the misuse of QR Code, renewing the code after a certain number of days.

Comment: Yes, but _how_ do you avoid that misuse, when I simply _change_ `date=20231030` to `date=20251231` in this URL that I already know now?

Comment: Good point @CBroe , Joshmoto sent us a solution in this regard. Thanks!

Comment: @Jim: Please carefully consider what will happen if users are able to create new arbitrary QR codes (with arbitrary point values), modify existing QR codes (to expire later / have more points), or redeem QR codes multiple times. All of this is possible with the approach you describe in the question. The base64-approach described below solves _none_ of these problems.

Comment: @Jim the previous comment by [at]He3lixxx is totally on point to be fair. My solution is totally useless due to the fact (base64'ed or OpenSSL Encrypted or just plain URL vars), if someone scans the QR code, what stops them from re-scanning the QR again? We can easily handle non logged users by passing url vars through the login form and easily handle QR expiry by now date... but what would make this question great is to describe exactly the usage, creation and distribution of your QR code for us to better understand the whole scenario :-)

Comment: Thanks, He3lixxx and joshmoto for taking time to help me. Yes, it is true that the repeating scan is a problem. I'd like the customer to read only one time when visiting the store. NextMoneyLLC sent a solution with date and password which I think can work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code. It includes a password to allow you to create some kind of security against misuse. Also, if you don't want people to use the QR Code you just change the password, and it would be redirected to an error page.

In regard to stopping the re-scaning and gaining recently points I added a line to detect the day of the scanning and then redirect to an error page when the user tries to rescan in the same day.

I included explanations inline with the code hope it helps you.
The code if for this example url: https://anysite.com/lp/?action=setpts&point=10&pass=thecustompassword

Parameters are "point" (number of points you want to give to the user) and "pass" (password to validate the QR Code).

Good luck!

```
function set_mycred_points($point, $pass) {
    // Define the correct passcode
    $correct_pass = "thecustompassword";

    // Check if the passcode is correct
    if ($pass !== $correct_pass) {
        wp_redirect('/qr-error/'); 
        exit; // Make sure to exit to prevent further execution
    }

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $today = date('Y-m-d');

    // Get the date when the user last performed the action
    $last_performed_date = get_user_meta($user_id, 'mycred_last_performed_date', true);

    if ($last_performed_date != $today) {
        // User has not performed the action today, so add points
        mycred_add('Store Visit Points', $user_id, $point, 'Earned Store Visit Points');

        // Update the date when the user last performed the action
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'mycred_last_performed_date', $today);
    } else {
        // User has already performed the action today, redirect to a specific page
        wp_redirect('/point-error/'); 
        exit; // Make sure to exit to prevent further execution
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'setpts' && isset($_GET['point']) && isset($_GET['pass'])) {
    $point = intval($_GET['point']); // Sanitize the point value as an integer
    $pass = $_GET['pass']; // Get the passcode from the GET parameters
    set_mycred_points($point, $pass);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @NextMoneyLLC, for the code! I'll try with it.